# Error de direccionamiento de pagina

Tags: php, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo una consulta, estoy haciendo un formulario para poder actualizar el precio de un material en especifico, el problemas es que ya a la hora de presionar el botón asignar hace la actualización de los datos (precio) en la base de datos correctamente pero me direcciona a una pagina en blanco (precio.php), como puedo hacer para que se quede en la misma pagina (mismo formulario) y tampoco me aparece el mensaje para confirmar si deseo editar el precio, cualquier ayuda me serviría de mucho

frm_new_precio.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>       
          <script >
              $(function() {               
                  //autocomplete
                  $("#material_name").autocomplete({
                     source: "formularios/auto_completar_material2.php", 
                      focus: function(event, ui) {
                          // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                          event.preventDefault();
                          // manually update the textbox
                         //$(this).val(ui.item.label);
                     },
                      select: function(event, ui) {
                          // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                          event.preventDefault();
                          // manually update the textbox and hidden field 
                         $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                         $("#codigo").val(ui.item.cod);
                         $("#cod").val(ui.item.cod);
                         $("#material").val(ui.item.cod);
                         $("#material_name").val(ui.item.label);
                     }                                       
                  });          
              });
          </script>  
          
          <script>
            function editar_precio(id){
        var 
        //From http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29
      //emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
      codigo = $("#cod"),    
      material = $("#material") 
      allFields = $( [] ).add( codigo ).add(material);
              
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
 
          if (valid){   
          // document.getElementById('comprobar_mensaje').innerHTML="<img src='http://localhost/sistema_mantenimiento/recursos/img/loading.gif' height='6%' width='6%' alt='' />";
           
          if (confirm(" ¿Desea modificar el precio del material? \n" + nombre.val() ) === true) {                       
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'formularios/precio.php', 
                        data: {ide: id, nombre: nombre.val()},             
                        dataType: "html",
                        error: function(data){
                            alert("error petición ajax");
                        },
                        success: function(data){                                                      
                            alert(data); 
                            $("#contenido").load("formularios/frm_new_precio.php")
                        }
                    });  
                   } 
                   else {
                   
                   }   
              
               
      }
      return valid;                            
     }
        </script>
         
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        // put your code here
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" hidden/>     
        <table class="display" style=" background-color:  #DCDCDC">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <br>
                        <label style='text-align: center; font-size: 125%'>Asignacion de precio</label>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody >                
                <tr>
                    <td>

                    <form action="formularios/precio.php" method="POST">
                        
                        <label >CODIGO:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cod" id="cod" style=" width: 7%" readonly />                        
                        <input type="text" name="material_name" id="material_name" style=" width: 82%"  />                        
                        <!--<a  onclick="limpiar_txt()" class="boton" title="Limpiar Nombre"><-</a>-->
                        <br>
                        <br>

                        <label >PRECIO A ASIGNAR:</label>                                           
                        <input type="decimal" name="precio_material" id="precio_material" style=" width: 15%"  />   <br>                    
                        <input type="submit" name="asignar" id="asignar" value="asignar"  onclick='editar_precio()' style=" float: right"  />
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </form>


          
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                
            </tfoot>           
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

precio.php

```
<?php
            include("conexion.php");
                   
            if(isset($_POST['asignar']))
            {
              $cod = $_POST['cod'];
              $nombre = $_POST['material_name'];
              $precio    =  $_POST['precio_material'];
                          
        
              if ($cod=="" || $nombre=="" || $precio=="")
              {
                echo "Todos los campos son obligatorios";
              }
              else
              {
                $_UPDATE_SQL=" UPDATE `movimientos`
                SET `precio`  = IF(`tipo_movimiento` = 'ENTRADA' , '$precio' , `precio`)
                WHERE `codigo_material` = '$cod' ";
                mysqli_query($conexion,$_UPDATE_SQL); 

              
              }
            }
            ?>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!---->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./recursos/css/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./recursos/css/estilo_index.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./recursos/css/estilo_data_table.css">  
        <!--<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./recursos/css/estilo_validar.css">-->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./recursos/css/estilo_frmsolicitud2.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./recursos/css/estilo_formularios.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./recursos/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>          
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./recursos/js/jquery-ui-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./recursos/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>         
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./recursos/js/funciones.js"></script>         
        
        <title>SISMANT</title>
    </head>
    <body id="fondo">
            
   
        <?php                
        // put your code here
        session_start();
        
        if(isset($_SESSION['nombre_usuario'])){
                //echo "Has iniciado Sesion: ".$_SESSION['nombre_usuario'];
                //echo "<br/> " ;
              //echo "Su privilegio es de: " .$_SESSION['privilegio_usuario'];
            }else{                
             header('location: ./formularios/login.php');
            }       
            
            $dias = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
            $meses = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
           
                    
               /* echo 'Hoy es ' .setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
                echo strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y"); */    
        ?>
        <div id="contenedor">
            
            <div id="cabecera">
                <span  id="logo"><img  src="./recursos/img/logo.jpg"></span>
                 
                <span id="titulo_principal"><br><a style="text-align: center; font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;">SISTEMA DE MANTENIMIENTO</a> <br>
                    <!--<a style="text-align: center; font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;">BIENVENIDO</a>-->
                    <br>
                    
                    
                   <!-- <a>
                        <?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>
                    </a>-->
                </span>
                
                
                    

                    <ul id="nav">
                        <li><a href="index.php">PÉRFIL</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML = '',$('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_new_user.php/?accion=edit')">Modificar Datos</a></li>
                                
                                
                                <?php
                                    if($_SESSION['privilegio'] == "administrador"){
                                       echo '<li><a target=_blank  href="recursos/admin_manual.pdf">Manual de Usuario</a></li> 
                                             <li><a target="_blank" href="formularios/z_z_backupdb.php">Respaldar BD</a></li>';
                                    }
                                    elseif ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == "usuario" ){
                                     echo '<li><a target=_blank  href="recursos/user_manual.pdf">Manual de Usuario</a></li> 
                                             <li><a target="_blank" href="formularios/z_z_backupdb.php">Respaldar BD</a></li>';
                                    }
                                    elseif ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == "limitado" ){
                                     echo '<li><a target=_blank  href="recursos/limit_manual.pdf">Manual de Usuario</a></li>';
                                    }
                                 ?>
                                <li><a  href="formularios/salir.php">Cerrar Sesión</a></li>                                
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                          <?php
                          if ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == "administrador"){
                              echo "
                <li ><a>ADMINISTRADOR</a>
                                  <ul>
                                  <li><a id='LinkUsuario' href='#' >Usuarios</a></li>
                                  <li><a href=# onclick=document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML='',$('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_fil_ord_bitacora.php/?accion=nuevo')>Bitacora</a></li>         
                                  </ul>
                                  </li>";
                              }                     
                              ?>
                        
                    <li><a>SOLICITUDES/ORDENES</a>
                        <ul>                            
                           <li> <a id="LinkNewOrden" href="#">Generar Orden de Trabajo</a></li>
                             <?php
                          if ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == "usuario" || $_SESSION['privilegio'] == "administrador"){
                              echo '
                                                                   
                                                                        
                                  ';
                              }                     
                              ?>  
                         <li> <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML = '',
                                       $('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_listar_ordenes_generadas.php')">Ordenes Generadas</a></li>
                           <li> <a id="LinkOrdenPendiente" href="#">Ordenes Pendientes</a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML = '',
                                       $('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_fil_ord_cerradas.php')">Ordenes Cerradas</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
               
                     <?php                   
                          if ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == "usuario" || $_SESSION['privilegio'] == "administrador"){
                              echo "
                                   <li ><a>INGRESOS</a>
                                    <ul>                                       
                            <li><a href=# onclick=document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML='',$('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_update_material.php/?accion=nuevo')>Agregar Stock</a></li>                                                        
                            <li><a href=# onclick=document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML='',$('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_new_category.php/?accion=')>Nueva Categor&iacute;a</a></li>
                            <li><a href=# onclick=document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML='',$('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_new_unit.php/?accion=')>Nueva U/M</a></li>
                            <li><a href=# onclick=document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML='',$('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_new_material.php/?accion=')>Nuevo Material</a></li>                            
                            <li><a href=# onclick=document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML='',$('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_new_applicant.php/?accion=')>Nuevo Solicitante</a></li>
                            <li><a href=# onclick=document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML='',$('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_new_depto.php/?accion=')>Nuevo Servicio</a></li>
                            <li><a href=# onclick=document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML='',$('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_new_precio.php/?accion=')>Ingresar Precio</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    </li>                                      
                                  ";
                              }                     
                              ?>  
                    
                    <li><a>CONSULTAS</a>
                        <ul>
                           <li><a id="LinkEntradaSalidaMateriales" href="#">Kardex</a></li>
                           <li><a id="LinkMateriales" href="#">Materiales</a></li>
                           <li><a id="LinkDepartamento" href="#">Servicios</a></li>
                           <li><a id="LinkCategoria" href="#">Categor&iacute;as</a></li>
                           <li><a id="LinkUnidad" href="#">Unidad de Medida</a></li>                           
                           <li><a id="LinkSolicitante" href="#">Solicitantes</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML = '',
                                       $('#contenido').load('formularios/cons_existencias_min.php')">Existencias Mínimas</a></li>                           
                           <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML = '',
                                       $('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_ord_x_serv.php')">Ordenes por Servicio</a></li>                           
                           <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML = '',
                                       $('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_ord_x_serv2.php')">Res. Estadístico-Ordenes</a></li>                           
                           <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML = '',
                                       $('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_tecnicos_x_orden.php')">Producción por Tecnico</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML = '',
                                       $('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_reporte.php')">Reporte General</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contenido2').innerHTML = '',
                                       $('#contenido').load('formularios/frm_kardex.php')">Kardex General</a></li>
                           
                           
                           
                           
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                     <!-- <li><a>INFORMACION ADICIONAL</a>
                         <ul>
                             <li><a href="">Salir</a></li>
                         </ul>
                     </li>-->
                              
                        <!--<li>Hoy es: <?php echo $dias[date('w')]." ".date('d')." de ".$meses[date('n')-1]. " del " .date('Y'); ?></li>-->
                    </ul>             
                
            </div>
            
            <div id="contenido" style=" background:  #DCDCDC">
                <h1>BIENVENIDO</h1>
                <h2>Hoy es: <?php echo $dias[date('w')]." ".date('d')." de ".$meses[date('n')-1]. " del " .date('Y'); ?> </h2>
               
            </div>
            <div id="contenido2" style=" background:  #DCDCDC">
           
            </div>
            
            <div id="pie_de_pagina">
                <br/>  <a style="text-align: center; font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;">ESTE SITIO ESTÁ ÓPTIMIZADO PARA UNA RESOLUCIÓN DE 1024*768PX </a><br/><br/>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Haz uso de Ajax o procesa el formulario en la misma página.

Comment: si proceso el formulario en la misma pagina a la hora de actualizar los datos me dirigía al mismo formulario pero sin el estilo css y sin las opciones que estan arriba como perfil, administrador, etc

Comment: Y no tienes guardados esos datos en variables de sesion ?

Comment: ahí añadí el archivo de index.php para que lo puedas ver amigo

Answer (score 0):

Pues en el PHP ponel que si es exitoso el cambio del producto te redirija con la siguiente linea en tu php

header("location:../pagina_del_formulario.php?resultado=1");

quedaria asi

```
<?php
            include("conexion.php");
                   
            if(isset($_POST['asignar']))
            {
              $cod = $_POST['cod'];
              $nombre = $_POST['material_name'];
              $precio    =  $_POST['precio_material'];
                          
        
              if ($cod=="" || $nombre=="" || $precio=="")
              {
                echo "Todos los campos son obligatorios";
              }
              else
              {
                $_UPDATE_SQL=" UPDATE `movimientos`
                SET `precio`  = IF(`tipo_movimiento` = 'ENTRADA' , '$precio' , `precio`)
                WHERE `codigo_material` = '$cod' ";
                mysqli_query($conexion,$_UPDATE_SQL); 
    header("location:../pagina_del_formulario.php?resultado=1");
              
              }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Aun que yo en lo personal mandaria el cambio en con un ajax o post con js asi evitarias refrescar la pagina, solo mandar los datos del formulario y que te renueve la pagina si es exitoso el resultado, digo es mucho mejor pienso yo xd

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, me sirvio de mucho, solo que al momento de que no se ha insertado algunos datos y muestra el error  "Todos los campos son obligatorios" tambien me direcciona a una pagina en blanco con el mensaje

Comment: pues pon esa misma linea en el el if , no solo en el else

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, aunque si quiero que lo direccione al formulario de frm_new_precio.php aparece como sin estilo css y solo muestra el muy formulario sin as otras opciones, te mostrare como queda el formulario

Comment: mmmm los estilos lo tienes todo en la cabecera de la pagina principal o lo tienes agregado en otra pagina por que si lo tienes por separado mejor ponlo en ambas, no pasada